# web applications in IIS7.5 on Windows 7 machine are unreachable

Tags: windows-7, iis-7.5

Two problems with a Windows 7 machine on this network:

- No one can access the web applications hosted in IIS.
- I am unable to ping this machine

I have turned off the Windows Firewall and have disabled the service.

**Is there a way to detect which application is blocking the incoming requests to IIS?**

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Turning off Windows firewall isn't going to do anything if it is behind a hardware firewall. What is the network config like?

Answer (score 0):

You can get stuck in all sorts of places.

You didn't mention what is in-between you and the win 7 machine, so I'm going to assume you're on something bigger than a lan.

When I get stuck like this, I'll use Trace Route ([tracert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracert))

For example, say between you and the server is 3 routers:  A, B, C

Trace-route and ping use the same protocol ([ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol)).

Ping tries to send a direct message from you to the server.  Trace Route sends:

1. you to router A
2. you to router B
3. you to router C
4. you to destination (in this case, your Win 7 machine)

(You can confirm this by watching the packets in a [packet](http://www.wireshark.org/) [sniffer](http://www.tcpdump.org/))

If trace route doesn't work (ie doesn't get from you to router A)   Then you know that you are blocking ICMP traffic.

If it gets to router B, but then stops, you know that router C is block ICMP.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen antivirus/internet security software block network traffic through it's own firewall. If you have anything like this on the PC, you'll need to turn it off as well, or configure it to allow traffic.